# Meteor.startup(func) - when is the DOM "ready" in Meteor?

Tags: dom, meteor

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup

Concerning `Meteor.startup(func)`

> On a client, the function will run as soon as the DOM is ready.

At what point is the "DOM ready"?

The reason why I ask is because you can have a Meteor template that uses many other templates (ie. other DOM elements) inside of it and have many other things loading at different times depending on how long those things take to load (ie. more DOM elements).

In the past I've loaded Javascript files on Meteor.startup but they were still loaded too early because the entire DOM actually had not been loaded yet.

```
Meteor.startup( function() {

  //load JS files now

});
```

So what does it mean by "DOM ready?" It most definitely does not mean "When the DOM is loaded in its entirety."

Answer (score 2):

Meteor.startup actually runs when all the files have completely downloaded from the server (javascript files). If you place your code to run at startup without putting it in a Meteor.startup it may not run because it would run where the JS/html has not been fully downloaded yet

This is when the 'DOM is ready', but not necessarily when your HTML is rendered, because this (the HTML) renders when the DOM is ready too.

If you're looking for something that runs after both the DOM is ready and after your page's html is ready look for the template's `.rendered` callback - http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

The confusion may come from the concept of `$(document).ready` in JQuery, but this applies because the page is already rendered on the server side so you can assume its also rendered on the client (since its downloaded that way). In Meteor pages are rendered on the client so there is this slight difference.

Comment: Can you explain the second paragraph? "because this renders when the DOM is ready too" What is "this" that you're referring to? So to summarize - When all the files are done downloading is when .startup is called. When the entire DOM is loaded and the HTML is rendered is when .rendered gets called.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny i meant the HTML. Yes exactly. I might add that the HTML for a specific template. When you use a router you may have templates that are not rendered until their path is called (for example /blog for a blog template)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the .startup method actually does on the client:

```
Meteor.startup = function (cb) {
  var doScroll = !document.addEventListener &&
    document.documentElement.doScroll;

  if (!doScroll || window !== top) {
    if (loaded)
      cb();
    else
      queue.push(cb);
  } else {
    try { doScroll('left'); }
    catch (e) {
      setTimeout(function() { Meteor.startup(cb); }, 50);
      return;
    };
    cb();
  }
};
```